# How to open a link though a clickable table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, web

I am very new to Web Development and is building a web-app using JSP and servlet. I have come up with a case where I want to show the details of particular order when it is clicked. The detailed view should open from right side slidingly.

I have recorded a screenshot from a popular website to show what I am looking for https://www.useloom.com/share/0e13308d7ae9424e9b0700049a3e6837

Please let me know what is the effect is known as and how can I implement using js or jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery developers usually do this though load() and click() methods (Though now is prefered on("click") method. This code sniped should help to figure it out.

```
$('a').on('click', function(e) {           
 var url = $(this).attr('href');
 $('#container').load(url); //create a div whose id is container to display content
 e.preventDefault(); //prevent the browser from following the link
});
```

That said, I had to warn you: stack overflow comunity is great, but not very patient with newbies. Make a search on a subject before ask next time.
Best regards.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the code, now I an learning the jQuery from the beginning and also thanks for the warning although I did a lot of research before posting the question but not no success.